# rails API Routing Duplication

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create some API in rails like this:

```
  #         /teachers   /teachers/:id
  # Get     index       show
  # Post    create    
  # Put                 update
  # Delete  remove      destroy
```

I used the code below to generate teachers:

```
  # teachers
  resources :teachers, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy] do
    collection do
      delete 'remove'
    end
  end
  delete '/teachers', to: redirect('/teachers/remove')
```

Since there are many objects such as 'programs', 'students', 'stuffs', now I use code like this to generate programs and others:

```
  # programs
  resources :programs, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy] do
    collection do
      delete 'remove'
    end
  end
  delete '/programs', to: redirect('/programs/remove')
```

I feel there are a lot of duplication, can I create some helpers to generate these API

Comment: `resources` is just a method--what have you tried? Might want to consider `except` though.

Comment: Take a look at this part: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints - You could set a generic route like `/:controller(/:action(/:id))` with constraints about the controller and action

Comment: I am thinking about how to encapsulation the model with the controllers, so when I want to get or save data from the database, I can just use the API which are defined in the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a lot of controllers where this is repeated, you can iterate:

```
[:teachers, :programs].each do |res|
  resources res, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy] do
    collection do
      delete 'remove'
    end
  end
  delete "/#{res}", to: redirect("/#{res}/remove")
end
```